# _this3 not a function (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, countdown

I have a simple countdown component where a user inputs two times and it counts down the seconds between them. The start, stop, and reset work. Except, when I reset the countdown and input two new times (without refreshing the page), I am hit with this error:

`TypeError: _this3.start is not a function`

`> 108 | <button onClick={(e) => this.start()}>Start</button>`

Below is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.start = this.start.bind(this);
    this.toTimestamp = this.toTimestamp.bind(this);
    this.getDifference = this.getDifference.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      input1: '',
      input2: '',
      countdown: null
    }
  }


input1ContentChange(e){
  const text = e.target.value;
  this.setState(()=>{
    return {input1: text};
  })
}

input2ContentChange(e){
  const text = e.target.value;
  this.setState(()=>{
    return {input2: text};
  })
}


toTimestamp(input){
  let time = input.split(':');
  let seconds = ((+time[0]) * 60 * 60) + ((+time[1]) * 60) + (+time[2]);

  return seconds;
}

getDifference(input1, input2){
  let difference = (this.toTimestamp(input2))- (this.toTimestamp(input1));

  if(this.toTimestamp(input2) < this.toTimestamp(input1)){
    alert("please input a later time in Time 2");
  }

  this.setState({
    countdown: difference
  })
}


start() {
  if(this.state.input1 === '' && this.state.input2 === ''){
    alert('please choose 2 times');
  }
  this.getDifference(this.state.input1, this.state.input2);
  this.start = setInterval((e) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {countdown: prevState.countdown - 1};
    });
      if(this.state.countdown <= 0){
        clearInterval(this.start);
      }
  }, 1000);

}

stop(){
  clearInterval(this.start);
}

reset(){
  clearInterval(this.start);
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {countdown: null, input1: '', input2:''}
  })
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Countdown Timer</h1>
        <p>Please choose two different times below</p>
          <div className="input1">
              <label>
                Time 1:
              <input type="time"
                  step="1"
                  min= "12:00"
                  max= "18:00"
                  value={this.state.input1}
                  onChange={(e)=> this.input1ContentChange(e)}/>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div className="input2">
              <label>
                Time 2:
              <input type="time"
                  step="1"
                  min="12:00"
                  max="18:00"
                  value={this.state.input2}
                  onChange={(e)=> this.input2ContentChange(e)}/>
              </label>
          </div>
          <button onClick={(e) => this.start()}>Start</button>
          <button onClick={(e) => this.stop()}>Stop</button>
          <button onClick={(e) => this.reset()}>Reset</button>
          <h3>{this.state.countdown}</h3>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The error is happening at the start function for restarting the countdown. When I check in my chrome tools using the React extension, the state is managed fine. It seems "this" is getting lost.

Comment: A potential problem I'm seeing is that you assign your interval to a value called `this.start` while already having a function called `start` bound to `this`. You should consider picking more explicit/meaningful names and, especially, different names to eliminate the risk of collision/unexpected variable reassignment altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying your class function. When your app loads, your class has a `start` method, but inside that method you do:

```
this.start = setInterval(...)
```

`setInterval` does not return a function, but an `id` that you can use later to clear the interval. Even if it did return a function, you probably don't want to be modifying your class methods at runtime.

I would suggest using another variable name:

```
this.intervalId = setInterval(...)
```